# How to pass variable form controller to blade templete in laravel 9

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-9

I want to show all the media files that the user have been uploaded in frontend but in blade template this shows an error `Undefined variable`, I have done everything right in my knowledge to solve this but it's not resolving.

[image]

I have tried `compact()` method but that can't solve the problem. I want the data from database and show in frontend but the variable from controller to blade template is not passing properly.

```
controller.php

public function show()
    {
        $uploads = media::with('user')
                ->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
                ->latest()
                ->get();

        return view('dashboard', compact('uploads'));
        
    }
```

```php
dashboard.blade.php

@foreach ($uploads as $media)
    <div class="p-6 flex space-x-2">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-600 -scale-x-100" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">

    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M8 12h.01M12 12h.01M16 12h.01M21 12c0 4.418-4.03 8-9 8a9.863 9.863 0 01-4.255-.949L3 20l1.395-3.72C3.512 15.042 3 13.574 3 12c0-4.418 4.03-8 9-8s9 3.582 9 8z" />

       </svg>
     <div class="flex-1">
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
     <div>
     <span class="text-gray-800">{{ $media->user->name }}</span>

     <small class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">{{ $media->created_at->format('j M Y, g:i a') }}</small>
     </div>
    </div>
  <p class="mt-4 text-lg text-gray-900">{{ $media->media }}</p>
</div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: "_this shows an error Undefined variable_" Please always post the complete error message you get (with file and line number)

Answer (score 1):

1. It may be that the media model is in uppercase :
   `$uploades = Media::with('users')...`

or its reference is not imported in your controller :

`use App\Models\Media;`

2. Write before `return view(...)` in controller :
   `dd($uploades);`
   What result do you see?